# Looping through a file with path and file names and within these file search for a pattern

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file called lookupfile.txt with the following info:

path, including filename

Within bash I would like to search through these files in mylookup file.txt for a pattern : myerrorisbeinglookedat. When found, output the lines where found into another recorder file. All the found result can land in the same file.

Please help.

Comment: What have you written so far?  How many entries are there in lookupfile.txt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can write a single `grep` statement to achieve this:

```
grep myerrorisbeinglookedat $(< lookupfile.txt) > outfile
```

Assuming:

- the number of entries in lookupfile.txt is small (tens or hundreds)
- there are no white spaces or wildcard characters in the file names

Otherwise:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  # print the file names separated by a NULL character '\0'
  # to be fed into xargs
  printf "$file\0"
done < lookupfile.txt | xargs -0 grep myerrorisbeinglookedat > outfile
```

- `xargs` takes output of the loop, tokenizes them correctly and invokes `grep` command.  `xargs` batches up the files based on operating system limits in case there are a large number of files.

Comment: Here is what I have currently:

Comment: #Get all user login
logdirectory="/sas/saslogs/Core"
searchstr="- Created grid job "
for fle in $( find $logdirectory -type f -name '*ObjectSpawner_'$logdate'*' );
do
      echo $fle>>/sas/results/attestlogfiles.txt
done

#Create var container to be searched
fname=/sas/results/attestlogfiles.txt
#Search for the "searchstr" - list - and output another file
while IFS= read -r $fname; do
  # print the file names separated by a NULL character '\0'
  # to be fed into xargs
  printf "$fname\0"
done < /sas/results/attestlogfiles.txt | xargs -0 grep $searchstr  > /sas/results/tmp.txt

Comment: Please add it to your question.